# "addon" is undefined in panel ( firefox-addon )

Tags: firefox-addon

I meet a strange thing with Firefox addon development. Why `addon` is undefined ?

*-- main.js --*

```
var login = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("login.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("login.js")
});

login.port.on('send', function onSend(login, password) {
  core.getTokens(login, password);
  login.hide();
});
```

*-- login.js --*

```
document.querySelector('#ok').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    addon.port.emit('send', document.querySelector('#login').value, document.querySelector('#password').value);
});
document.querySelector('#cancel').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    addon.port.emit('close');
});
```

I got this error: `login.js: addon is not defined`. So, what's wrong? Thanks.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Scripting%20Trusted%20Panel%20Content)

Comment: why `addon.port`?  Why not `self.port`?

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_port#Accessing_port_in_the_Content_Script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addon` object is defined when your script is included through a `script` tag by the `login.html` file.

Since you use the `contentScriptFile` option, you have to use the `self` object.